# spring boot - web mvc test does not find controller mapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, spring-mvc-test

In [this spring-boot project](https://github.com/MaxHoefl/springboot-jpademo) the following `WebMvcTest` fails because the `GET /items` mapping from the `ItemController` is not found

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(ItemController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class Test_ItemController {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private ItemDao dao;

    @MockBean
    private CartDao cartDao;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        // setting up mock response
        Cart cart = new Cart();
        cart.setId(1);

        Item item = new Item();
        item.setCart(cart);
        item.setItemName("toothbrush");
        item.setId(1);
        //---------------------

        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(item);

        given(this.dao.findAll()).willReturn(items);
        this.mvc.perform(get("items").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
2018-02-26 12:10:45.816  WARN 12252 --- [           main] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : 
   No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [items] in DispatcherServlet with name ''

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = items
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Accept=[application/json]}
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Here is the controller (just a little experiment, so don't focus on missing ResponseEntity and missing service layer)

```
@RestController
public class ItemController 
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ItemController.class);

    @Autowired ItemDao dao;

    @GetMapping("items")
    public List<Item> getAll()
    {
        List<Item> res = new ArrayList<>();
        dao.findAll().forEach(res::add);
        return res;
    }

    @PostMapping("items")
    public Item addItem(@RequestBody Item item)
    {
        return dao.save(item);
    }

    @GetMapping("items/{item_id}")
    public Item getItemById(@PathVariable("item_id") long item_id)
    {
        Item item = dao.findById(item_id).get();
        LOG.info(" ---------------- Retrieved item: {}", item.toString());
        return item;
    }
}
```

This is the pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RC1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, ok I forgot the slash in the endpoint

`this.mvc.perform(get("/items").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk());`

simple comment instead of downvote would suffice imho